# How can I display hexadecimal numbers in C?

Tags: c, format, integer, printf, hex

I have a list of numbers as below:

> 0, 16, 32, 48 ...

I need to output those numbers in hexadecimal as:

> 0000,0010,0020,0030,0040 ...

I have tried solution such as:

```
printf("%.4x", a); // Where a is an integer
```

But the result that I got was:

> 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 ...

I think I'm close there. How can I fix it?

I'm not so good at `printf` in C.

Comment: Try `printf("%d: %.4x\n", a, a)`, I think your `a` doesn't have the value you think it has.

Comment: yes, you're right. i was absent minded. sorry for this foolish question...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try:

```
printf("%04x",a);
```

- `0` - Left-pads the number with
  zeroes (0) instead of spaces, where
  padding is specified.
- `4` (width) - Minimum number of
  characters to be printed. If the
  value to be printed is shorter than
  this number, the result is right justified 
  within this width by padding on the left 
  with the pad character.  By default this is 
  a blank space, but the leading zero we used 
  specifies a zero as the pad char.
  The value is not truncated even if the result is
  larger.
- `x` - Specifier for hexadecimal
  integer.

More [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: it results in: 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 ... what I need is: 0000,0010,0020,0030,0040 ...

Comment: hmm, how weird ... I tried it but always show up as 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 (I use Eclipse in Ubuntu, gcc...)

Comment: @tsubasa - print them out as decimal integers at the same time, just to check that the rest of your code does what you think.

Comment: The original `%.4x` format notation was fine and achieves the same results as `%04x`.  The issue was primarily the data supplied to the `printf()`.

Answer (score 9):

I use it like this:

```
printf("my number is 0x%02X\n",number);
// Output: my number is 0x4A
```

Just change number "2" to any number of characters you want to print ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no problem. It does print the way you want.  Alternatively, you can do this:

```
printf("%04x",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned int i;
    printf("decimal  hexadecimal\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 256; i+=16)
        printf("%04d     0x%04X\n", i, i);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints both decimal and hexadecimal numbers in 4 places with zero padding.