# Display hex values on LCD

Tags: c

I have data stored in `text_buf[4] = {0x1d, 0x72, 0x2f, 0x32}`.When I send it to display on LCD, it displays some garbage. I understand that LCD displays only string, how do I make it to display hex values that is stored in `text_buf`? Are there any C examples for this? Please do let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649026/how-to-display-hexadecimal-numbers-in-c

Comment: do you have any code? what is the desired output? if your LCD prints only strings - convert the buffer to a string and print it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `snprintf()` family to format your `text_buf` (or any data) to a `char` array and call your LCD's display routine.

```
char line[256];
snprintf(line, sizeof(line), "%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", text_buf[0], text_buf[1], text_buf[2], text_buf[3]);
LCD_print(line); // LCD's display routine
```

[Reference for format sequence](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html).

Comment: You "misspelled" `snprintf()`. Also, no cplusplus.com, please. Firstly because it's bad, secondly because this is a C question.

Comment: Ha, I'll "correct the spelling" then. But that reference is to the C library and so I think it is suitable.

Comment: unfortunately, that's not the case. I suggest you take a look at [a true C reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html).

Comment: @H2CO3: technically, that's a POSIX reference.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It is. But at least it's official and it doesn't suffer from hundreds of fundamental errors. And it's about C, not C++.

Comment: I intended to provide an easy reference of formatting sequence to the OP (who seems to be new to C). The official things are not user friendly IMHO.

Comment: Using C++ documentation for the C stdlib is not `programmer friendly` , nor is it `computer friendly` .

Comment: @leesei Why do you think that a C++ reference is more "user friendly" than a C one? (Also, as I just stated, it's wrong. Would you rather supply your user with a wrong but "friendly" reference than a correct but more technical one? I hope not.)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Check out my updated answer, hope it's better now...

Comment: Do not take this as a challenge, but I genuinely are not aware of the difference of the `printf()` API/implementation difference in C and C++. I only meant the tabulated layout and examples are more user friendly for a learner.

Comment: @leesei No problem. There's no difference (well, there should be no difference...) between `printf()` in `<stdio.h>` and `printf()` in `<cstdio>`. It's only that one should not contribute to the common misconception that "C is a subset of C++", since it isn't. I (and apparently others too) felt that you kind of supported this by treating C and C++ things as if they were interchangeable. I see that you wanted to do something good :) This is just a piece of advice.

Comment: @H2CO3 K, but C tutorial are indeed hard for beginners (they are all ASCII text ;-p). Do you guys have any recommendations beyond SUS?

Comment: @leesei, for learning C? K&R's 2nd Ed. is a good book as well Kochan's `Programming in C`

Comment: Any other online reference? (I'll keep SUS in my bookmark from now on.)

Answer (score 3):

Be safe and use `snprintf()`. Also add a loop to generalize the task and to decrease redundancy:

```
char text[0x1000]; // or however many
size_t n = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]); i++) {
    int delta = snprintf(text + n, sizeof(text) - n, "%02x ", buf[i]);
    if (delta < 0)
        break; // handle error!

    n += delta;
}
```

([documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html))

---

Technically, the documentation above concerns POSIX, not only standard C. So in case anyone wonders: section 7.19.6.5 of [the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (I couldn't find the C11 one online) concerns this very function. Clause 7.19.6.1.8 describes the conversion specifiers.

Comment: I originally down voted this answer because it is overly complex in my opinion. H2C03 and I had a long "discussion" and in the end he pointed out to me that down votes are for technically incorrect answers or spam. I am removing my down vote because his answer is not incorrect nor spam..