# RGB to Hex converter

Tags: r, colors, hex, rgb

Suppose I have this vector

```
x <- c("165 239 210", "111 45 93")
```

Is there a neat package to convert RGB values to hex values in R? I found many javascript ways but not one for R.

```
x <- "#A5EFD2" "#6F2D5D"
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just split the string up, and then use `rgb`:

```
x <- c("165 239 210", "111 45 93")
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x)
    rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], maxColorValue=255))
#[1] "#A5EFD2" "#6F2D5D"
```

Comment: For me, I was going from `col2rgb` so the following shorthand works (and would be similar for the example here): `do.call(rgb, as.list(col2rgb('red')/255))`

Comment: Just FTR: after splitting the string, using a function makes this more versatile: 
`rgb_2_hex <- function(r,g,b){rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255)}`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based off the [answer to this same question by Hong Ooi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574676/4200548) but instead defines a function `rgb2col` function that **takes as input a matrix of rgb values of the form returned by `col2rgb`**. This means we can convert from hex to rgb and back again with just these two functions.
In other words, `rgb2col(col2rgb(x))` = `col2rgb(rgb2col(x))` = `x`.

## Input structure

Start with a matrix of RGB colors of the form returned by `col2rgb()`. For example:

```
      [,1] [,2]
red    213    0
green   94  158
blue     0  115
```

## Function

This function will convert the matrix to a vector of hex colors.

```
rgb2col = function(rgbmat){
  # function to apply to each column of input rgbmat
  ProcessColumn = function(col){
    rgb(rgbmat[1, col], 
        rgbmat[2, col], 
        rgbmat[3, col], 
        maxColorValue = 255)
  }
  # Apply the function
  sapply(1:ncol(rgbmat), ProcessColumn)
}
```

## Example use case

You might want to modify a color palette manually but not feel as  comfortable working with hex numbers. For example, suppose I want to darken a vector of two colors a little.

```
# Colors to darken
ColorsHex = c("#D55E00","#009E73")

# Convert to rgb
# This is the step where we get the matrix
ColorsRGB = col2rgb(ColorsHex)

# Darken colors by lowering values of RGB
ColorsRGBDark = round(ColorsRGB*.7)

# Convert back to hex
ColorsHexDark = rgb2col(ColorsRGBDark)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a numeric matrix and use `colourvalues::convert_colours()`

```
colourvalues::convert_colours( 
  matrix( as.numeric( unlist( strsplit(x, " ") ) ) , ncol = 3, byrow = T)
)
# [1] "#A5EFD2" "#6F2D5D"
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use the `sprint` function in R and the hints in the following post: [How to display hexadecimal numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649026/how-to-display-hexadecimal-numbers-in-c)