# R Hex to RGB converter

Tags: r

Suppose I have this color in HEX values (including alpha):

`x <- "#FF2400FF"`

Is there a neat package to convert HEX values to RGB values in R? Or a simple bit of code to do that?

`[#1] c("36 0 255")`

Edit: This is the opposite way of [RGB to Hex converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574480/r-rgb-to-hex-converter) question

Comment: http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/col2rgb.html

Comment: `?col2rgb` and `?rgb` for the opposite

Comment: loki, it's not. It's just the opposite way

Comment: thanks @cath. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments already given, you can use this code:

```
x <- "#FF2400FF"
paste(as.vector(col2rgb(x)), collapse = " ")
#> [1] "255 36 0"
```

However, looking at your requested result, it seems that you have the alpha-value as first hex-number in your `x` - so you need to create a substring:

```
x <- "#FF2400FF"
paste(as.vector(col2rgb(paste0("#", substr(x, 4, 10)))), collapse = " ")
#> [1] "36 0 255"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Example 1

You can get the RGB values as a *1-dimensional* **array**

```
hex.rgba.color <- "#FF2400FF"
rgb.array <- col2rgb( hex.rgba.color )
print( rgb.array )
```

**Output**

```
      [,1]
red    255
green   36
blue     0
```

## Example 2

You can get the *red*, *green*, and *blue* values respectively as **integers**

```
hex.rgba.color <- "#FF2400FF"
rgb.array <- col2rgb( hex.rgba.color )
message( rgb.array[1] ) # red
message( rgb.array[2] ) # green
message( rgb.array[3] ) # blue
```

**Output**

```
255
36
0
```

## Example 3

You can also get the *alpha* value as **integer** by simply adding `alpha=TRUE`

```
hex.rgba.color <- "#FF2400FF"
rgba.array <- col2rgb( hex.rgba.color, alpha=TRUE )
message( rgba.array[1] ) # red
message( rgba.array[2] ) # green
message( rgba.array[3] ) # blue
message( rgba.array[4] ) # alpha
```

**Output**

```
255
36
0
255
```

## Example 4

You can get all the values as **vector** by typecasting the array with `as.vector()`

```
hex.rgba.color <- "#FF2400FF"
rgba.vector <- as.vector( col2rgb( hex.rgba.color, alpha=TRUE ) )
print( rgba.vector )
```

**Output**

```
[1] 255  36   0 255
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, HEX colors strings are splitted and converted to integers:

```
for (color in heat.colors(10)) {
  hex_splitted_color = c(paste('0x', substr(color, 4, 5), sep = ''),
                         paste('0x', substr(color, 6, 7), sep = ''),
                         paste('0x', substr(color, 8, 9), sep = ''))
  print(strtoi(hex_splitted_color))
}
[1]   0   0 255
[1]  36   0 255
[1]  73   0 255
[1] 109   0 255
[1] 146   0 255
[1] 182   0 255
[1] 219   0 255
[1] 255   0 255
[1] 255  64 255
[1] 255 191 255
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Cath commented, it exists a function to do that:

```
col2rgb(heat.colors(10))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
red    255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255   255
green    0   36   73  109  146  182  219  255  255   255
blue     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   64   191
```