# How to convert vector of RGB values to Hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb

I have a CSV of RGB values i.e:

```
[1]230-000-070
[2]255-000-000
[3]204-077-242
...
...
(40 more rows)
```

I want to apply these to a discrete scale on a raster in ggplot2, which is looking for Hex codes as opposed to RGB

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c("#E60046", "#FF0000", "#CC4DF2"))
```

I think this function is what I need - how would I go about applying it to a vector?

```
rgb2hex <- function(r,g,b) rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255)
```

Comment: Related [RGB to Hex converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574480/rgb-to-hex-converter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split original vector with RGB values using `strsplit` function and then apply `rgb2hex` using `do.call` on a list produced by `strsplit` (output is a list).

```
# Input vector
RGB <- c("230-000-070", "255-000-000", "204-077-242")
# Function to apply
rgb2hex <- function(r, g, b) {rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255)}
# Split orignal vector and pass to rgb2hex with do.call as list
do.call(rgb2hex, strsplit(RGB, "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
rgb2hex <- function(x) rgb(substr(x, 1, 3), substr(x, 5, 7), substr(x, 9, 11), maxColorValue = 255)
```

Output:

```
rgb2hex(rgb)

[1] "#E60046" "#FF0000" "#CC4DF2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to split the r,g,b values into separate columns when you first read the csv, by specifying `-` as the separator.  Demonstrated here using `library(data.table)`, although you could equally well use read.csv instead:

```
x = fread('my.csv', sep='-')
x[, rgb(V1,V2,V3, maxColorValue = 255)]
```

NB to test on the example data, you can use:

```
x = fread("
230-000-070
255-000-000
204-077-242", sep='-')
```