How to extract hex code from single named color?
This might be a duplicate (I will remove question if it is), but please read first.
Mock plot:
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = hp, y = "", fill = as.factor(gear))
       )+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF3300", "#006600", "purple"))

Note that 2 colors were defined using hex codes, but one was defined using a name recognised by R, "purple".
How do we get the hex color code for what R calls "purple"?
I found several suggestions on SO, none of them works.
Solution 1
ggplot_build(p)$data

Solution 2
g <- ggplot_build(p)
unique(g$data[[1]]["fill"])

Solution 3
ld <- layer_data(last_plot())
(head(ld))

All the above solutions return something like this:
#     fill
#1 #FF3300
#2 #006600
#3  purple 

That is, they do not return the hex code corresponding to "purple".
I know how to return hex codes for entire palettes. But not for a single color, here, "purple".

not exacting from thr ggplot object but ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574480/rgb-to-hex-converter

thanks! but indeed I need to extract from ggplot2

You can get the rgb code for purple using col2rgb
> col2rgb("purple")
      [,1]
red    160
green   32
blue   240

Then use those codes in rgb function to get the hex code
> rgb(160, 32, 240, maxColorValue=255)
[1] "#A020F0"


you can pass t(col2rgb("purple")) instead of typing the individual values
